# Customize the shape of a scatterview

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2008, pixelsense, scatterview

I'm currently using the Surface SDK 1.0 in Blend and VS2008, and I've encountered a problem: I use a scatterview over the whole screen. I also have a grid in the middle of the screen. The panel in the middle is quite annoying because my scatterviewitems can easily get lost BEHIND the grid, and since the grid is locked in position, there is no way for me to retrieve them.

It would be desireable to add "walls" around the grid, so that my scatterviewitems would bounce off it, as it does at the edges of the scatterview.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Can objects within a scatterview interact, or bounce off each other?

Comment: This honestly sounds more like a usability design issue. Why is that grid there, why is it locked in place, and why does it have to be on top of the scatterview?

Answer (score 1):

Just hook up to "ScatterManipulationCompleted" and check if the item is under your grid. If yes start a Storyboard which moves the Center of your ScatterViewItem back out of the grids background.

Also take a look at the [surface community forums](http://community.surface.com/), there are a lot posts regarding ScatterViewItem and collision detection.